# In what ways does the number of legs affect an animal's functioning?

Tags: evolution, zoology, anatomy, locomotion

After much research, I've only been able to find specific examples of leg-number's impact on locomotion and dexterity (and/or object manipulation). I feel as though there must be other ways it has a role in an animal's anatomy and function.

Examples I imagined but couldn't evidence include;

1. Respiration rate (relating to S.A. for tracheoles in Arthropods).
2. Similar to no. 1 but not quite the same - the structure of the circulatory system.
3. Insects'/tetrapods' stabilty (especially regarding an ant's capacity for load-bearing).
4. The brain's capacity for higher order thought processes (does conscious control of more limbs limit this?).
5. Efficiency of thermoregulation (also related to differences in S.A.).

I would most appreciate an explanation for how a given animal's number of legs gives it an aptitude for a type of locomotion (such as sprinting, climbing or burrowing). I would also like simple yes/no answers to the ideas listed above - as to whether they are implicated in the number of legs.